# asp.net mvc 2 to mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4.1

I would like to update my project from:

- ASP.NET MVC 2 with Entity Framework 4.

to

- ASP.NET MVC 4 and Entity Framework 4.1

How can this be done?

Comment: Hi Jean, I noticed below that tutorials for upgrading are posted below, but... what is to stop you from copying the files from your current project creating a new project and then pasting the files in there. Sure you will have to import your Dll references but I cant really see why it would be a huge change. I know my company made the change quick and painless

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may take a look at the ASP.NET MVC 4.0 release notes which explain how to [upgrade from an ASP.NET MVC 3 application](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806). And the release notes of ASP.NET MVC 3.0 explain [how to upgrade from ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading).

As far as upgrading from EF 4.0 to EF 4.1, it's as simple as updating the assembly reference. Of course if you wanted to do Code First approach you will have to make more extensive modifications.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing it manually which will indeed take a lot of effort....why not check out [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15377863/39532) and  use [ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Upgrader](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) to go from MVC2 -> MVC3 and [UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4](https://nuget.org/packages/UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4) to go from MVC3 -> MVC4.