# "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server." in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I attempted to run my web service through visual studio. I faced an issue like :

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.

Failed to register URL "http://localhost:63591/" for site "xxxxxx" application
"/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being
used by another process. (0x80070020)

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I saw the task manager and found that PID 4 is used by System and its Description is `NT Kernel & System.`
So I tried to stop the `http service`.
All dependency services stopped. But I am facing an issue in stopping http service like

```
The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later.
```

So, I tried to stop and start the service manually. But the End process is disabled. 
It will be helpful if anyone could help with this issue

Comment: seeing the issue after updating Windows 10: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/580466/cannot-start-iis-express-0x80070020.html

Comment: fwiw, the above link points to a link [here](https://programmingflow.com/2015/08/28/solved-iis-express-failed-to-register-url-access-is-denied.html), which says you can try `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::`

Answer (score 225):

I had a similar issue when trying to run a project from Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10. 
The application could not start because the port was apparently being used by another process. However, the `netstat` command showed that the port was not being used by any application.

After spending 2-days Googling I found a solution that worked for me. 
The port I was trying to use was in the excluded port range which you can see by running the command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

The culprits that reserved these ports in my case were Docker for Windows and Hyper-V

**The Solution**

I uninstalled Docker (as I did not need it) and disabled Hyper-V. 
To disable Hyper-V: Go to: Control Panel-> Programs and Features-> Turn Windows features on or off. 
Untick Hyper-V and restart the computer.

After the restart the command
`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` showed no ports reserved.

I then added the port for my application to the excluded port range by running the following command from an elevated command line:

```
netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=50403 numberofports=1 store=persistent
```

Then I reenabled Hyper-V (Docker can be reinstalled if needed) and restarted the computer again.

Hyper-V now reserved its ports without interfering with the port used by my application:
[Reserved Port Ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I7QR.png)

Comment: This worked for me, except I need Docker so I just disabled it on start up instead of uninstalling it.

Comment: Like @Cory I changed my port in vs to be something outside the ranges, annoy because now i have to change referencing apps every time i do this but better than a full restart.

Comment: Disabling Hyper-V and rebooting fixed it for me

Comment: I changed the port and then just had to run the command below to get it to work, thanks!
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:49914/ user=Everyone

Comment: Also changing the port number used by the project may be "not so friendly". Check [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/353750/cannot-change-port-number.html) on a solution for changing both http and https port numbers (the last "trick" works only for https port number).

Comment: I had Docker installed in Ubuntu running on WSL2. Disabling Hyper-V did not resolve the issue. Instead I just changed the port on the URL in launchSettings.json - on "applicationUrl".

Comment: Installing WSL2 caused this problem for me.  Changing the port in VS to avoid the excluded ranges worked for me.

Comment: Wow! Thank you thank you thank you thank you!!!!!
This issue has been a random annoyance for months now and I couldn't find an article that actually explain why this is happening. I have no idea why Hyper-V is activated on my laptop. Apparently, it allows you to run a virtual machine on your laptop, but since I have no plan of ever doing that, I just disabled it. Good riddance! I hope thats the last time I get this annoying error!

Comment: See the answer from Chris Schiffhauer on how to use netstat to figure out which processes are using a certain port. In my case, it was GlobalProtect, which is required by my company. Nothing I can do there, so I am forced to change the port in launchsettings.json.

Comment: This. For me, the port I was using was inside that exclusion list. Picked a port outside it and everything works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 182):

From https://www.davidsalter.co.uk/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-0x80070020/

Error code `0x80070020` means `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, which in the case of IIS Express (or IIS) means that the port that it is attempting to listen on is being used by another process.

Use the `netstat` command to find out which application is using the port.

```
netstat -ao | findstr <port_number_to_search_for>
```

The `a` parameter tells netstat to display all connections and listening ports.

The `o` parameter tells netstat to display the process ID associated with the connection.

Running the above netstat command will produce output such as:

```
C:\>netstat -ao | findstr 4026
TCP    12.0.0.1:4026        cs-pc:4026         LISTENING       9544
```

The last number displayed (9544 here) is the process ID.

Comment: This can be made considerably faster with the `-n` switch as well -- it uses "numeric" output, which means it doesn't waste time querying DNS in order to resolve IP addresses into hostnames.

Comment: I just wanted to mention for others that this didn't find anything using the port but changing the port localhost ran on did fix the issue. So if all else fails, just change it anyways.

Comment: I ran taskkill /PID 4 /F from a PowerShell window that was run as administrator and I got an error message 'Access denied'

Comment: I've run "netstat -ano | findstr <port_number_to_search_for>" with the port that I'm trying to run on, and it isn't found.

Answer (score 95):

Solution that worked from me is,

To fix this you must temporarily disable the winnat service, this is simply done by running this command (must be run as administrator)

**net stop winnat**

Start your docker services and start winnat again

**net start winnat**

Solution posted at http://www.herlitz.nu/2020/12/01/docker-error-ports-are-not-available-on-windows-10/

Comment: Upvoted! But please note, that this can kill WSL's network features untill you reboot

Comment: I don't have Docker installed, but this fixes this recurring issue with Windows 11 and IIS Express.

Comment: pulling my hair, this was it,

Comment: Thanks! This has been a recurring issue that have haunted me for the last two years.

Answer (score 51):

This Answer Work For Me
**1-open cmd with Run As Administrator**
2-type    **net stop winnat**
you got
"The Windows NAT Driver service was stopped successfully."
3- then type **net start winnat**
you got
The Windows NAT Driver service was started successfully.
**after that go to visual studio and press ctrl+f5**

Comment: This works for me too. Thank you so much for this solution. I have been struggling with this issue for a while, and it happened randomly on different solutions across different machines.

Comment: Why does this fix the issue? What is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: Works for me. Awsome.

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem. I just restarted Visual Studio and it worked.

Comment: In my case, my Windows 10 box blue-screened, and I had to reboot **twice**. Other web site projects worked fine (different local port), and none of the other answers here worked. Changing the port for the project didn't fix it either. There must be some other config in IIS Express itself.

Comment: It seems like this happens to me whenever I run a project in VS 2019 with debugging using F5, then later try to run it without debugging using Ctrl+F5 which is when it fails. A restart fixes it, though I wish I could actually prevent it from happening in the first place.

Comment: There is a golden rule of .NET development, which I keep forgetting: if something goes wrong, restart Visual Studio (and make sure you do so with admin rights).  Time and again I come to SO and read through complicated solutions before someone reminds me of this!  Restarting solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same Issue. As @Kautsky Lozano mentions above *Another application is using that port.*

So [for a Windows OS] just:

- Open Resource Monitor (Task Manager -> Performance -> Open Resource Monitor )
- Click on the *Network* tab.
- And at *TCP Connections* find the application that uses the Local Port that IIS Express uses and close it. (it was firefox on my case)

Answer (score 21):

#### If netstat doesn't show anything already using the port

`netstat -ano | findstr <your port number>`

The port might be excluded, try this command to see if the range is blocked by something else:

`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

You can try to unblock the range from the start port for a number of ports (need Command Prompt with Administrator):

`netsh int ip delete excludedportrange protocol=tcp numberofports=<number of ports> startport=<start port>`

For me I couldn't unblock these, I just got "Access is denied", so I ended up having to pick another port for my site.

Comment: Nothing else but this helped. 
I could see the range included my port number `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`. Lot of time was wasted until I found this to get it resolved.

Thanks lot @john Leonard

Answer (score 18):

After updating Windows 10 and/or Visual Studio 16+ it might happen due to an [internal bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/556100/iisexpress-failed-to-register-url-for-site.html) that IISExpress fails to register any development website because it no longer accepts `localhost` connections.

To fix the issue, you just have to register again the binding. To do so, run from an administrative shell the following command:

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

Additionally, some reported that restarting the `winnat` service in combination with the command above, helped in their new OSes.

Comment: This bug is so random... Thanks your response fixed my issue!

Comment: That was the only thing that fixed this crazy issue. Thank you!

Comment: I needed to use this in combination with "net stop winnat" and "net start winnat"

Answer (score 13):

## IIS Express Failing to Start Solution in Visual Studio

- Go to Task Manager
- Search for "Application Frame Host" Process
- End this Process
- Try to Run Again

`If not successful, Try run this command in cmd: "net stop winnat"`

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem after we had upgraded a solution from Visual Studio 2012 to 2015. I had come here and ran `netstat` only to find that no other application was using the same ports. It turns out I had the same sites with the same ports mapped in the `applicationhost.config` at `Users/<username>/Documents/IISExpress/config` and the `applicationhost.config` in the `.vs` folder inside my solution. I should note that the problem didn't start right after the upgrade either. It just start failing consistently one morning. A couple reboots didn't seem to solve the problem either.

Removing the conflicted sites from the one stored in my Documents and restarting Visual Studio solved the problem.

Comment: This helped me: the `applicationhost.config` is in the `.vs\config` folder under your solution folder.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, doing the following did the trick:

- Delete the Site from .vs\\config\applicationhost.config
- Delete the Site from Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
- Delete the IISUrl from the .csproj

When I restarted Visual Studio, it assigned the project a completely new port number and ran perfectly

Comment: deleting `iisExpress` which includes `applicationUrl` and `sslport` from launchsettings.json did it for me with the other steps.

Comment: removing IISExpress files in document folder help me

Answer (score 4):

to summarize all the answers. There are 2 solutions. Both worked for me.

- **Solution #1** Kill the app that uses the same port.
- **Solution #2** Configure IIS Express to use a different port for your project.

**Solution #1**
(supposing the port in the error message was 443)
Run in the command line:

```
netstat -ao | findstr 443
```

it returns: `TCP    0.0.0.0:443            pe01:0                 LISTENING       2904`
The last number (thanks to @chris-schiffhauer) is PID to kill. Go to the Task Manager -> Processes -> [Show Processes From All users], Kill a process with PID=2904. In my case, it was VmWare host.

**Solution #2**
(Supposing message was: *Failed to register URL "http://localhost:433/" for site "MyProject.Website0"...*).
Open the following file in notedpad++: `C:\Users\MY_USER_NAME\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` Find in it a line containing:

```
<site name="MyProject.Website0" id="...
...
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:localhost" />
            </bindings>
```

Either change `433` to something else, like `4330` or delete the conflicting `<binding.../>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue even though netstat did not show any conflicts.

The following fixed it for me:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Open up File Explorer
3. Navigate to the folder of the offending project
4. Delete the **obj** and **bin** folders
5. Delete the ***.user** file (this is probably optional)
6. Restart Visual Studio and try again

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when [upgrading an MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655808/asp-net-mvc3-to-mvc4-upgrade-tool). I copied over the newer-MVC .csproj over my existing .csproj file then worked back to a fully working Project. What I failed to consider is the existing port number in the old .csproj. The new project had a new port number, yet shared the Project/Assembly Name. That was enough to make IIS Express lose its mind and throw this exception.

Just digging the old port number out of git and changing the IIS Express URL to include it in Project Settings was enough to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Close visual studio
2. delete ".vs" folder
3. Try change port "localhost:8080"

It worked for me.

Comment: Worked like charm!

Answer (score 3):

Reason for this error that is you give the wrong port number to your application.

```
just use http ports for your application to run
```

use the port near to 8080 number,
i.e:

> localhost:8090

to change the port for you application in visual-Studio

```
goto project properties > web > Server > ProjectUrl
```

---

Answer (score 3):

This indeed happened after installing `Docker`.

**Steps to Resolve**:

1. **Checked `Network` under `Resource Monitor`**:

   - `Port 66666` was not being used by any network process.
2. **Tried to Quit `Docker Desktop`**:

   - `Port 66666` still not available.
3. **Checked excluded port range**:  `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

   - Port is indeed in the `Exclusion Ranges`.
4. **Try to Untick `Hyper-V` in `Turn Windows Features On and Off`**:

   - **Cannot Find `Hyper-V`** in `Turn Windows Features On and Off`.
5. **Attempted to remove Port from the Exclusion Ranges**:
   `netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=66666 numberofports=1 store=persistent`

   - Failed with result `Element Not Found`
6. **Inspired by this [link](https://superuser.com/a/1610009) to attempt to restart network services**:

   1. `net stop winnat`

      - after running this command, confirmed `port 66666` already disappeared from `Exclusion Ranges` by running `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`
   2. stopped other network services just to be more assured

      - `net stop LanmanWorkstation`
      - `net stop WlanSvc`
      - `net stop WwanSvc`
   3. restart the network services

      - `net start WwanSvc`
      - `net start WlanSvc`
      - `net start LanmanWorkstation`
      - `net start winnat`
7. **Confirmed unavailable port is available now**:

   1. `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

      - `Port 66666` no longer in the `Exclusion Ranges`
   2. `IIS Express Web Server` can be launched successfully.
8. **Launched Docker Again**:

   - `port 6666` still available to be used.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest first pass at this without getting into the command console is to just shut down all applications (including VS), then launch VS by itself and try it again.  There is likely another application like your browser causing the conflict.
In my case Chrome caused it and was solved when shutting everything down and restarting VS.  I opened Chrome again and everything was fine.

The netstat stuff above is useful, but to me that's only if you can't do what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Web Project
Properties >> Web >> Project Url >> Change port
i.e: http://localhost:22345/ => http://localhost:22346/
Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

I was able fix this problem by removing everything from `<site>` to `</site>` tags in

`Users/<username>/Documents/IISExpress/config/applicatiohost.config` file

```
<sites>
  <site>
     .
     .   ===> remove this content including the <site> and </site> tags.
     .
  </site>
</sites>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Port numbers do not match**

In my case the problem was in my Bindings Tags found in the config file in .vs under my solution folder, the port numbers did not match. The bindings were as follows

```
<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":16433:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

And in my settings i had url set as `http://localhost:1943/`

So what i did was to delete  inside binding and run my web app, then it generated new binding with a different number then i copied the new generated port to my settings, then the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem in Visual Studio 2019 today and spent 3 hours before finally figuring out the problem.  Visual Studio uses 2 files to track the SSL port number, so you have to fix both and you have to fix both while Visual Studio is closed.  The two files are the applicationhost.config file that is in the .vs\???\config folder of your solution; and also the .csproj.user folder of your web project.
Edit both files and removing the offending configs.  Maybe even just delete both files. Then re-open your app in Visual Studio. Good luck!

Comment: If your solution contains a plain old fashioned website (not a web application) then the port numbers are also in the solution file .sln

Comment: For old fashioned website editing both .(sln solution file and applicationhost.config file) worked.

Answer (score 1):

Having just wasted half a day trying to fix this same issue, I felt I should add the solution which eventually worked for me.

**TL;DR** If `netstat`indicates that the problematic isn't in use, still try a few others in a totally different range

I've run into this problem before but usually find restarting visual studio, changing ports (increment by 1) or rebooting do the trick. However on this occasion none of this helped, and `netstat` wasn't finding a conflicting process. I even reinstalled IIS and visual studio and removed several other programs which I suspected could be interfering. It seemed as though IIS was trying to launch multiple instances of the same site.

Eventually I tried running `netstat` without `findstr`. I visually scanned the list of active ports and noticed that although the ones I had tried were not listed, there were a few processes using ports in a similar range. So instead I looked for a range which was free, picked a port number and that seems to now be working.

I'd love to hear if anybody can explain why this might have worked?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2019 Version 16.10.0 Preview 2.0 and I just went to here:

[image: untick and save anв tick]

Unchecked `Enable SSL` => Save => check it back => Save.

Answer (score 1):

**Restarting the PC** usually fixes this in case you tried restarting VS with no luck.

For me, I've been working for years on the same VS version and on the same PC with no updates whatsoever. However, suddenly today I encountered this error, and it did not make any sense.

I Hope this helps whoever might come across this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following already:

- Restarted Visual Studio
- Check all available ports that might be listening to my specific number but it always return zero results. No processes is listening in my port.
- I also tried using this  but zero results.

  **netstat -aon | find ":80"**
- I also tried using but also return zero results.

  **netstat -ao | findstr**

So what I did is delete this "**Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe**" then my project successfully started and launch in browser. The error was fixed. I am not sure why but it works.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Installing a component of the IIS seems to be doing the trick**

In my case, the easiest solution (and what works constantly) is to try installing a component of the IIS from the Windows 10 (eg. FTP Server). This can be done by going to the `Control panel` -> `Program & features` -> `Turn Windows features On or Off`, and then turning on an IIS component.

Strangely enough, even though the error is related to the IIS Express Web server (and not IIS), installing an extra IIS component, it obviously alters something in the system. After that, the system becomes functional again.

I have tried million things and it didn't seem that the port was somehow reserved by an other app and neither that it maybe was some kind of a firewall problem.

Something that I observed was that this issue was popping up when network related applications were installed or were opened. Examples of these were the update of my *Docker Desktop* app, installation of *VMWare Workstation*, *Hyper-V* activities (like running a VM), etc. I didn't pinpoint the exact reason but I know that somehow these are related.

Answer (score 0):

My site worked fine, then started getting this error for no reason.  I had many things open (including several VS projects) and didn't want to reboot.  I also didn't want to waste time with any of these solutions, so I just changed the port number on the Project URL of the project properties... instant success.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is far easier. Just go to the status bar , look for the IIS express icon and stop the site.
Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69841149/8390589

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, close VS, rename the folder where your website is located and open the website again in VS (`File` --> `Open Web Site...`)