# Unable to connect to IIS Express when reserving port range

Tags: docker, iis, port, iis-express, hyper-v

I had the problem like many others that Hyper-V and/or Docker randomly reserves port ranges on startup which eventually prevented me from starting my IIS WebApi.

I followed the Answer on this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59610178/7993447
And reserved my API Port myself in the excludedportrange but my API is still unable to connect on the reserved ports.

Does anybody know how I can reserve a range of ports in the excludedportrange so that I can use them with IIS without Hyper-V stealing them from me?

Comment: Based on the documentation from Microsoft, you can only configure your IIS/IIS Express sites to use a port that's not in the reserved TCP port range. You cannot reserve your own port for IIS or IIS Express.

Comment: But why does it work for the people in the Answer I mentioned?

Comment: you can try to restart VS and deleting the hidden folder .vs in the root folder and tested it again.

Comment: still doesn't work ...

Comment: Here is a similar question you can use as a reference.[link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3171).