# Unable to launch IIS Express in Visual Studio after power outage occurred while the web app was open in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-express

A web app was open in Visual Studio 2019 when a power outage occurred. Now I'm getting the message below. What is "the file" that is being referred to in the error message, and how can it be freed up?

P.S. This not a case of the [port number being in an excluded range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116292/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-in-visual-studio). I checked as recommended in that question.

> Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.
>
> Output from IIS Express: Failed to register URL
> "http://localhost/65439/" for site  application
> "/".  Error description: The process cannot access the file because it
> is being used by another process.

NOTE: I have a battery backup that's supposed to shut my system down gracefully after 15 minutes in the event of a power outage; but Windows updates seem to routinely screw things up for it, and it didn't work this morning when it was needed, even though its battery is (and was) at 100%, and we had only a very brief outage lasting about 15 seconds. When I went to check on the computer, it was off, and upon rebooting, a number of apps reported that they had not been shut down normally.