# How to upgrade an MVC 2.0 project to MVc 4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to upgrade an mvc 2.0 application to mvc 4.0.

This is what I tried
1>Installed mvc 4.0
2>Changed the project to target .net framework 4.0.

How ever when I check the project references, the System.web.mvc being targeted is still version 2.0.0.0.

Do I manually delete these references and add them again?

Comment: Did you try to search for the answer first? Look at "[asp.net mvc 2 to mvc 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282395/asp-net-mvc-2-to-mvc-4)" for example...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Migrating from Asp.net MVC2 to MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107191/migrating-from-asp-net-mvc2-to-mvc4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, delete the references to System.Web.Mvc and re-add them.  This is in accordance with the [release notes for upgrading](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading) from MVC 2 to MVC 3, and the same principal applies going to MVC 4.

> In Solution Explorer, delete the reference to System.Web.Mvc (which points to the DLL from version 2), then add a reference to System.Web.Mvc (v3.0.0.0).

(or to v4.0.0.0 in your case)